# Calculating year, month, days between dates in google apps script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I have calculated using the below function and it gives the o/p in the format of "X YEARS, Y MONTHS, Z DAYS" and for some dates its giving some wrong o/p. I think I did some calculation missing in the formulas.

The function is,

```
/**
 * @param {Date} startdate
 * @param {Date} enddate
 * @return {String}
 */
function leasePeriodCalc(startDate,endDate)
{
  var sdate=startDate;
  var edate=endDate;
  edate.setDate( edate.getDate()+1);
  edate=new Date(edate);
  if(sdate.valueOf()>edate.valueOf()){
    return('0');
  }
  else{
    var years=((((edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate())<0 ? -1:0)+((edate.getMonth()+1)-(sdate.getMonth()+1)))< 0 ? -1 : 0)+(edate.getFullYear()-sdate.getFullYear());
    var months=((((edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate())<0 ? -1:0)+((edate.getMonth()+1)-(sdate.getMonth()+1)))< 0 ?12:0)+((edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate())<0 ? -1:0)+((edate.getMonth()+1)-(sdate.getMonth()+1));
    if((edate.getMonth()-1)!=1.0)
    {
      var days=((edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate())< 0 ?new Date(edate.getFullYear(), edate.getMonth(),0).getDate():0)+(edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate());
    }
    else
    {
      var days=((edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate())< 0 ?new Date(edate.getFullYear(), edate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate():0)+(edate.getDate()-sdate.getDate());
    }
    var day;
    var month;
    var year;
    if(years>1)year= years+ 'Years';
    else year=years+'Year';
    if(months>1) month= months+ 'Months';
    else month=months+'Month';
    if(days>1) day= days+ 'Days';
    else day=days+'Day';
    if(years==0&&months!=0&&days!=0) return(month+', '+day);
    else if(years!=0&&months==0&&days!=0) return(year+', '+day);
    else if(years!=0&&months!=0&&days==0) return(year+', '+month);
    else if(years==0&&months==0&&days!=0) return(day);
    else if(years==0&&months!=0&&days==0) return(month);
    else if(years!=0&&months==0&&days==0) return(year);
    else if(years==0&&months==0&&days==0) return(day);
    else if(years!=0&&months!=0&&days!=0) return(year+', '+month+', '+day);
  }
}
```

if you gives the i/p as below it returning the false o/p:

28th feb 2013 - 28th feb 2014

Expected o/p : 1 YEAR , 1 DAY

Given o/p    : 1 YEAR , 4 DAYS

But if I select 28th feb 2013 - 27th feb 2014 means, It gave the correct o/p:

Expected o/p : 1 YEAR

Given o/p    : 1 YEAR

Please advice to correct my fault if I did anything.

And also I have to tell that I'm not setting the rules n all. In general a month is calculating as per the days lying on the month.

For example, If we get a loan from a bank we ll pay the interest per month only even that month may have 30 days or 29 days or 28 days or 31 days.

And also if we take a room for monthly rental means, We ll pay the rent per month only rite? even it can be from 20th March - 19th April. Even it contains 31 days it is said to be one month only. Please help me to conclude this.

Tnx,
CL.

Comment: Best advice I can give you is to use moment.js for manipulating date values (see http://momentjs.com/ )

Comment: Why would expect difference from 28th feb 2013 - 28th feb 2014 to be 1 year 1 day?

Comment: Why would you expect the difference between 28th feb 2013 - 27th feb 2014 to be 1 year instead of 11 months and 27 days?

Comment: @HMR, As you asked if I exclude the end date means it ll be the 11 months and 27 days. But I need to calculate include the end date. So it should be 1 year for the period between 28th feb 2013 - 27th feb 2014.

Comment: I've modified the code a little, it should do what you'd like it to do (see the comments about including the end date)

Answer (score 28):

For complex date/time manipulations in JavaScript I find that the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library can really help. I wrapped it up into an Apps Script library, which you can include using the project key [MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48](https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48/8). I used it to take a crack at this problem, although I may have missed some edge cases.

```
// Load the library (key: MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48).
var moment = Moment.load();

function getDuration(startDate, endDate) {
  var start = moment(startDate);
  var end = moment(endDate);
  var units = ['years', 'months', 'days'];
  var parts = [];
  units.forEach(function(unit, i) {
    var diff = Math.floor(end.diff(start, unit, true));
    if (diff > 0 || i == units.length - 1) {
      end.subtract(unit, diff);
      parts.push(diff + ' ' + unit);
    }
  })
  return parts.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, @Eric. How did you wrap moment for consumption by GAS?

Comment: I would also like to know how to wrap a JavaScript lib for Google Apps Script.

Comment: The script changed its id to [15hgNOjKHUG4UtyZl9clqBbl23sDvWMS8pfDJOyIapZk5RBqwL3i-rlCo](https://script.google.com/home/projects/15hgNOjKHUG4UtyZl9clqBbl23sDvWMS8pfDJOyIapZk5RBqwL3i-rlCo/edit)

Answer (score 4):

You can include `moment.js` as an external dependancy and use it inside Google App Script project. Refering to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231921/5429123 article, you can do something like this.

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js').getContentText());
var date = moment().format("MMM Do YY");
Logger.log(date)
```

This will get you the last version of moment.js (2.22.2 as of 2018/10/25), compared to the old 2.4.0 available as a GAS library (like the accepted answer suggests).

PS - This works!

Comment: As of 2018 this is the best way to load moment.js (or any other 3rd party library) in Google Apps Script. This will get you the latest version, since the accepted answer's library is very old (2.4.0 compared to 2.22.2)

Answer (score 1):

Following Code Work for me 
Make sure u associate moment.js in script before executing

```
  var moment = Moment.load()

  var StartDate= new Date(StartDate1);
  var DD1 = StartDate.getDate();    
  var MM1 = StartDate.getMonth(); 
  var MM1=MM1+1                 //As Month Start with Zero
  var YYYY1 = StartDate.getYear();

  var EndDate= new Date(EndDate1);
  var DD = EndDate.getDate();    
  var MM = EndDate.getMonth(); 
  var MM=MM+1                 //As Month Start with Zero
  var YYYY = EndDate.getYear();



  var a = moment([YYYY, MM, DD]);
  var b = moment([YYYY1, MM1, DD1]);
  return a.diff(b, 'days')
  Logger.log(a.diff(b, 'days') )
```

Answer (score 0):

*Second attempt:*

```
function periodCalc(startDate, endDate) {

  var output = '';

  var sYear = startDate.getFullYear();
  var sMonth = startDate.getMonth();
  var sDay = startDate.getDate() - 1;
  var eYear = endDate.getFullYear();
  var eMonth = endDate.getMonth();
  var eDay = endDate.getDate();

  var tMonths = eYear * 12 + eMonth - sYear * 12 - sMonth;
  var days = eDay - sDay;

  if (days < 0) {
    tMonths--;
    var sDate = new Date(sYear, sMonth + tMonths, sDay);
    var eDate = new Date(eYear, eMonth, eDay);
    days = (eDate.getTime() - sDate.getTime()) / 86400000;
  }

  if (tMonths < 0) return '0';
  var months = tMonths % 12;
  var years = (tMonths - months) / 12;

  output += (years == 0 ? '' : (', ' + years + ' Year' + (years == 1 ? '' : 's')));
  output += (months == 0 ? '' : (', ' + months + ' Month' + (months == 1 ? '' : 's')));
  output += (days == 0 ? '' : (', ' + days + ' Day' + (days == 1 ? '' : 's')));

  return output.substr(2);
}
```

However an issue remains when the start date is the first day of a month, and the end date is the last day of the month. So for example, 1 Jan 2013 to 31 March 2013 will return 2 months, 31 days. Is this the desired result?

---

*Edit: first attempt (which is flawed, see first comment):*

I must admit my brain was hurting a bit looking at the code, which I'm sure would only have a minor error in logic somewhere. I thought it would be quicker if I tried re-writing it from scratch, but I think it would need some further testing (it works with my limited testing so far):

```
function periodCalc(startDate, endDate) {
  var output = '';
  endDate.setFullYear(endDate.getFullYear(), endDate.getMonth(), endDate.getDate() + 1);
  var sYear = startDate.getFullYear();
  var sMonth = startDate.getMonth();
  var sDay = startDate.getDate();

  var eDay = endDate.getDate(); 
  var days = eDay - sDay;
  if (days < 0) {
    var eopm = new Date(endDate);
    eopm.setDate(0);
    days = eDay + eopm.getDate() - sDay;
    endDate.setDate(eDay - days);
  }

  var eMonth = endDate.getMonth();
  var months = eMonth - sMonth;
  if (months < 0) {
    months = eMonth + 12 - sMonth;
    endDate.setMonth(eMonth - months);
  }

  var eYear = endDate.getFullYear();
  var years = eYear - sYear;
  if (years < 0) return '0';

  output += (years == 0 ? '' : (', ' + years + ' Year' + (years == 1 ? '' : 's')));
  output += (months == 0 ? '' : (', ' + months + ' Month' + (months == 1 ? '' : 's')));
  output += (days == 0 ? '' : (', ' + days + ' Day' + (days == 1 ? '' : 's')));

  return output.substr(2);
}
```

Comment: Great work man and as I tested your code for the period of **29th - Feb - 2012 to 28th - Feb - 2013** is giving **1 Year 1 Month** which is wrong and for the period of **31st - March - 2013 to 30th - April - 2013** is giving **2 Months** which is also wrong o/p. Pls check these scenarios and Pls guide me. Otherwise all other scenarios are moreover perfect...

Comment: Many thanks for the bug report. I have changed the logic a bit and re-written. But note the potential issue.

Comment: 2 months, 31 days is not the desired result for 1 Jan 2013 to 31 March 2013, The desired result is 3 months. And also for the scenarios like 31 March 2013 to 30 April 2013 the desired o/p is 1 Month 1 Day, But its giving 1 Month only. Pls take a look on it also Mr. AdamL, Tnx.

Comment: "for the scenarios like 31 March 2013 to 30 April 2013 the desired o/p is 1 Month 1 Day"... so 31 March to 29 April will be 1 month only? Doesn't seem very intuitive - but you're setting the rules, so just thought I should confirm first before re-writing code.

Comment: Ya Mr. AdamL from 31 March to 29 April will be 1 Month only.

Comment: I'm not setting the rules n all. In general a month is calculating as per the days lying on the month. For example, If we get a load from a bank we ll pay the interest per month only even that month may have 30 days or 29 days or 28 days or 31 days. And also if we take a room for monthly rental means, We ll pay the rent per month only rite? even it can be from 20th March - 19th April. Even it contains 31 days it is said to be one month only. Pls help me to conclude this. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I wrote a while ago, it's not fully tested but think it should do what it's supposed to do

[UPDATE]: fixed the bug but still acting funny when low date is feb 29 and diff is more than one year

```
function dateDiff(a,b){
    var low = (a>b)?b:a,
    heigh = (a>b)?a:b,
    diff = {
        years:0,
        months:0,
        days:0
    },
    tmpDate,
    tmpMonth;
    //if you'd like the diff to be including the the last day
    // of the end date you can do: lob.setDate(low.getDate()+1);
    if(low==heigh){return diff;}//a===b no difference
    diff.years=heigh.getFullYear()-low.getFullYear();
    tmpDate=new Date(low.getTime());
    tmpDate.setFullYear(low.getFullYear()+diff.years);
    if(tmpDate>heigh){
      diff.years--;
    }
    low.setFullYear(low.getFullYear()+diff.years);
    tmpMonth=heigh.getMonth()-low.getMonth();
    diff.months=(tmpMonth<0)?tmpMonth+12:tmpMonth;
    tmpDate=new Date(low.getTime());
    tmpDate.setMonth(low.getMonth()+diff.months);
    if(tmpDate>heigh){
      diff.months--;
    }
    low.setMonth(low.getMonth()+diff.months);
    while(low<heigh){
        low.setDate(low.getDate()+1);
        diff.days++;
        if(low>heigh){
          low.setDate(low.getDate()-1);
          diff.days--;
          break;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}


var a = new Date(2013,9,30);
var b = new Date(2014,1,26);
console.log(dateDiff(a,b));
//next one is a bit buggy, one might say it's
// 1 year and 1 day if considoring end of feb 2000
// to 1st of mar 2001
var a = new Date(2000,1,29);
var b = new Date(2001,2,1);
console.log(dateDiff(a,b));
```

Comment: Nice work @HMR, But some small fixes needed for the scenarios like 26 Feb 2013 - 30 March 2013 is giving 33 days, 27 Feb 2013 - 30 March 2013 is giving 32 days(i.e., if the end date is last but one date of the month means it return the wrong o/p). Pls clarify this doubt and moreover the calculation is perfect. Tnx.

Comment: Are you sure? I've copied and pasted the code in the console in firebug and when doing var a = new Date(2013,1,26);//Feb 26
var b = new Date(2013,2,30);//Mar 30
console.log(dateDiff(a,b));
I get Object { years=0, months=1, days=4}

Comment: There is a bug in the code; the following will give an incorrect diff:var a = new Date(2013,9,30);
var b = new Date(2014,1,26);
console.log(dateDiff(a,b));

Comment: Tnx for the clarification. If you find any more solution regarding this pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative of Date.Diff. xDate is a wrapper over Date Javascript object:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Date Wrapper
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var kDate = function () {
    "use strict";
    var dat = NaN, that = this;
    switch (arguments.length) {
    case 0: dat = new Date(); break;
    case 1: dat = new Date(arguments[0]); break;
    default:
        dat = new Date( arguments[0] || null, arguments[1] || null, arguments[2] || null, arguments[3] || null, 
                        arguments[4] || null, arguments[5] || null,  arguments[6] || null);
    }
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype).forEach(function(prop) {
        that[prop] = function () { 
            return dat[prop].apply(dat, arguments); 
        };
    });
    return this;
};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date).forEach(function(prop) {
    if (["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype"].indexOf(prop) < 0) {
        kDate[prop] = Date[prop];
    }
});

kDate.MAXDATE = 8640000000000000;
kDate.MINDATE = -8640000000000000;
kDate.YEARZERO = -62167132800000;
kDate.YEAR = 31536000000;
kDate.MONTH = 2592000000;
kDate.DAY = 86400000;
kDate.HOUR = 3600000;
kDate.MINUTE = 60000;
kDate.SECOND = 1000;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// kDate.diff()
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
kDate.diff = function(date1, date2) {
    var d1, d2;
    d1 = kDate.MAXDATE + (typeof date1 === 'number' ? date1 : date1.getTime());
    d2 = kDate.MAXDATE + (typeof date2 === 'number' ? date2 : date2.getTime());
    diff = new kDate(NaN);
    diff.diffDate1 = new kDate(typeof date1 === 'number' ? date1 : date1.getTime());
    diff.diffDate2 = new kDate(typeof date2 === 'number' ? date2 : date2.getTime());
    diff.diffTotalMilliseconds = d2 < d1 ? d1 - d2 : d2 - d1;
    diff.setTime(kDate.YEARZERO + diff.diffTotalMilliseconds);
    diff.diffTotalSeconds = diff.diffTotalMilliseconds / kDate.SECOND;
    diff.diffTotalMinutes = diff.diffTotalMilliseconds / kDate.MINUTE;
    diff.diffTotalHours =   diff.diffTotalMilliseconds / kDate.HOUR;
    diff.diffTotalDates =   diff.diffTotalMilliseconds / kDate.DAY;
    diff.diffYears =        diff.diffDate1.getUTCFullYear() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCFullYear();
    diff.diffMonth =        diff.diffDate1.getUTCMonth() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCMonth();
    diff.diffDate =         diff.diffDate1.getUTCDate() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCDate();
    diff.diffHours =        diff.diffDate1.getUTCHours() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCHours();
    diff.diffMinutes =      diff.diffDate1.getUTCMinutes() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCMinutes();
    diff.diffSeconds =      diff.diffDate1.getUTCSeconds() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCSeconds();
    diff.diffMilliseconds = diff.diffDate1.getUTCMilliseconds() - diff.diffDate2.getUTCMilliseconds();
    return diff;
};
kDate.prototype.diff = function (date) {
    return kDate.diff(this, date);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the example here:
http://ditio.net/2010/05/02/javascript-date-difference-calculation/

Much cleaner code and easier to read. (and it works!) ;-)