# How to use locale moment.js in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use this library http://momentjs.com/ with key MHMchiX6c1bwSqGM1PZiW_PxhMjh3Sh48 [How do I use momentsjs in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410210/how-do-i-use-momentsjs-in-google-apps-script)

```
var moment = Moment.load();
var d = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY");
Logger.log(moment(d).format('LL'));
```

and I get date in correct format in English, but I need it in Russian.  When I add the line:

```
var moment = Moment.load();
moment.locale('ru');
var d = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY");
Logger.log(moment(d).format('LL'));
```

It doesn't work and I get notification - Cannot find function locale in Object function (b, c, d, e) {...}.  Is it something wrong in my code?

Comment: have you loaded the `ru` locale? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

Comment: hmm, says locale isn't a function, perhaps you have an old version of moment.js and need to use `moment.lang('ru');` instead

Comment: Yes, it's seems library use the old version of script... I took the script from the site momentjs.com with locales and this code:

       moment.locale('ru');
       var d = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY");
       Logger.log(moment(d).format('LL'));

works fine now! Thank you all for answers =)

Answer (score 1):

You need the library which contains locales - located here:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment-with-locales.js
Also you have a couple of coding errors:

```
var d = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY");
```

At this point d is a text string - not a moment object.
Try this instead:

```
moment.locale('ru');
var d = moment();
Logger.log(d.format('LL'));
```

Should work..

But note moment.js by itself doesn't support locales.

Comment: how to find the Project Key for libraries?

Answer (score 1):

With latest moment.js (2.18.1) you may do it like this:

```
function testMomentLocaleRussian() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.js').getContentText());

  moment.locale('ru');
  var m = moment();
  Logger.log(m.format('LL'));
}
```

In order to use latest moment.js remove the old library from google app scripts and just use the `eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch` like my example above. Replace 2.18.1 with latest version.

This link provides all moment.js versions you can use from cdnjs (or host moment.js on your own server):

> https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/