# How do I add the Luxon library google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, libraries, external, luxon

I need to add the Luxon library to my google sheet script. Where do I find the ID of the Luxon library, or are there other ways?

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22411885/7215091

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Luxon can be also used with CDN. [Ref](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/luxon) When `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.4/luxon.min.js` is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script of Luxon is used by copying to the script editor.

1. Please access `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.4/luxon.min.js` with your browser.
2. Copy and paste the script from the URL to the script editor of Google Apps Script.
3. When the following sample script is used, a result like `2024-03-31T09:45:27.040+09:00` is obtained.

   ```js
   function myFunction() {
     const res = luxon.DateTime.now().toISO();
     console.log(res); // 2024-03-31T09:45:27.040+09:00
   }
   ```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the script of Luxon is loaded when the script is run.

1. When the following sample script is used, a result like `2024-03-31T09:45:27.040+09:00` is obtained.

   ```js
   function myFunction() {
     // Load library.
     const url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.4.4/luxon.min.js";
     eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

     // Use library.
     const res = luxon.DateTime.now().toISO();
     console.log(res); // 2024-03-31T09:45:27.040+09:00
   }
   ```

#### Note:

- I cannot test all methods of luxon. So, I'm not sure whether all methods can be worked.