# Timezone conversion in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone, dst, formulas

I know this looks simple.

In a Google spreadsheet, I have a column where I enter time in one timezone (GMT)
And another column should automatically get time in another time zone(Pacific Time)

```
 GMT      | PT
----------|------------
 5:00 AM  | 9:00 PM
```

As of now I am using

```
 =$C$3-time(8,0,0)
```

The problem here is, I want to change the time formula for Daylight savings.

Is there any function or script available which can take the daylight saving into calculation automatically.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Short answer

There is no built-in function but you could build a custom function.

### Example

```js
/**
 * Converts a datetime string to a datetime string in a targe timezone.
 *
 *@param {"October 29, 2016 1:00 PM CDT"} datetimeString Date, time and timezone.
 *@param {"Timezone"} timeZone Target timezone
 *@param {"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a z"} Datetime format
 *@customfunction
 */
function formatDate(datetimeString,timeZone,format) {
  var moment = new Date(datetimeString);
  if(moment instanceof Date && !isNaN(moment)){
    return Utilities.formatDate(moment, timeZone, format)
  } else {
    throw 'datetimeString can not be parsed as a JavaScript Date object'
  }
}
```

NOTE:

`new Date(string)` / `Date.parse(string)` implementation in Google Apps Script doesn't support some timezones abbreviations.

From https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format

> There exists no international standard that specifies abbreviations for civil time zones like CET, EST, etc. and sometimes the same abbreviation is even used for two very different time zones.

### Related

- [Get UTC offset from timezone abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60147015/1595451)

---

## Explanation

In order to consider daylight saving time zones the input argument for of the value to be converted should include the date, no only the time of the day. You could set a default date and time zone to build the datetimeString by concatenating it before calling the formula.

```
=formatDate("October 29, 2016 "&A2&" GMT","PDT","hh:mm a")
```

For the target timezone besides the three letter abbreviation we could use [TZ database names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) like `America/Los_Angeles`, example:

```
=formatDate("October 29, 2016 "&A2&" GMT","America/Los_Angeles","HH:mm")
```

If timezone abbreviation and TZ name fails for the datetimeString use time offsets (i.e. UTC-4).

## See also

- [Calculating year, month, days between dates in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149760/calculating-year-month-days-between-dates-in-google-apps-script/)

## References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I found that I need to RTFM, and that I was inputting my data in slightly incorrect format, which was throwing off the entire thing

Comment: Hi @Rubén. Thanks for a great function. I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to solve & I hope you can assist.

I'm in Australia, and we have timezones that change to DST at different times of the year. So I'm trying to use the timezone format like Australia/Sydney. The problem is, it works in the output (as you mentioned in your update) but not in the input. I've tried numerous different versions and have had no luck. Do you have any advice?

Another strange thing is the input seems to take some timezones (like GMT and UTC), but not others (like AEST or AET). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I thought I should give some examples.

EG this works: =converttz("October 09, 2020 11:00 AM PDT","Australia/Sydney","dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a")

But this doesn't:

=converttz("October 09, 2020 11:00 AM AET","Australia/Sydney","dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a")

Nor does:

=converttz("October 09, 2020 11:00 AM Australia/Brisbane","Australia/Sydney","dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a")

Comment: @Luke I updated my answer: tl;dr: Not all timezone abbrevitions / names are supported by Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update @Rubén. What a shame! I love the simplicity of your script, but since I'm dealing with Australian timezones, it looks like I'm going to have to implement Ryan's solution with moment.js. Hopefully, this will help many others though.

To add to your clarification, for others - it seems like other timezones are fine for the output. It is just the input that is limited.

Comment: @Luke consider to use `zone            =       (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone` (+0000) instead of three letter abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggeation @Rubén. However, as I understand it, this doesn't take into consideration DST. I would have to manually adjust for each timezone, right?

Answer (score 16):

### This tutorial was amazingly helpful: https://davidkeen.com/blog/2017/01/time-zone-conversion-in-google-sheets/

> Google Sheets does not have a built in way of converting time zone data but by using the power of Moment.js and Google’s script editor we can add time zone functionality to any sheet.

These are the files I copied into my script project:

- https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js saved as moment.js
- https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js saved as moment-timezone.js

Make sure you add the moment.js script first and have it above the moment-timezone.js script because moment-timezone.js depends on it.

Then in your *other* script project, your Code.gs file can look like this:

```
var DT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

/**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946815/timezone-conversion-in-a-google-spreadsheet/40324587
*/
function toUtc(dateTime, timeZone) {  
  var from = m.moment.tz(dateTime, DT_FORMAT, timeZone);//https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/
  return from.utc().format(DT_FORMAT);
}

/**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946815/timezone-conversion-in-a-google-spreadsheet/40324587
*/
function fromUtc(dateTime, timeZone) {
  var from = m.moment.utc(dateTime, DT_FORMAT);//https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/
  return from.tz(timeZone).format(DT_FORMAT);
}
```

[image]

Comment: While moment.js could save a lot of programming in other cases, for this specific case the built-in `Utilities.formatDate(...)` does a good job. Don't you think?

Comment: @Rubén I never want to have to think about whether to use PST or PDT. It feels redundant and error-prone if I've already specified the date. I'd rather be able to just specify PT or "America/Los_Angeles" for Pacific Time and have the system handle it.

Comment: On an "international project" (I'm in Mexico and my client is in Spain) I recently changed GMT+1 to Europe/Madrid and it's working fine, so i think that it should work too for America/Los_Angeles

Comment: @Rubén Then I'd need to manage how many hours to add or subtract from UTC depending on the time of year. It's the same problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't don't follow you. Why do you need to manage how many  hours to add/substract in the context of this question?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but check the results of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40324587/470749 for these: `myFunction("October 29, 2016 1:35 PM UTC","PST","YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a")`, `myFunction("October 29, 2016 6:35 AM PST","UTC","YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a")`, `myFunction("April 9, 2016 10:35 AM PDT","UTC","YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a")`, `myFunction("April 9, 2016 5:35 PM UTC","PDT","YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm a")`. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Rubén And what I've been saying is that it's often (or always) preferable to be able to specify your output time zone without specifying whether the season is appropriate for Daylight Saving. E.g. I don't want to need to specify PST vs PDT if I've already specified my input date is in October. The formula should automatically choose the appropriate Pacific Time time zone for that season.

Answer (score 3):

**The easiest method is using a simple calculation.**

Use =NOW() command in sheets and subtract it with the time difference divided by  24.

Example:
IST to Colombia

```
=NOW()-(10.5/24)
```

The time difference from India to Colombia is 10hours and 50min, we need to subtract it from the "Now" time and divide it by 24.

If the time zone is ahead of your place, then you need to add it.
Example:

IST to JAPAN:

```
=NOW()+(3.5/24)
```

=Now is set to US time by default, you can change it under general in settings.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqVFu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1IC.png)

Comment: Are you sure that 10 hours and 50 minutes translates to 10.5?

Comment: Yeah, try the above formula with google sheets if you have any doubts.

Comment: The time difference between Colombia and India is 10 hours and **30 minutes** (0.5 x 1 hour), hence the "10.5".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (convert Manila Time to Sydney Time and automatically adjust for daylight saving time) when I found this page.

I didn't want to have a custom function but I found that, in Sydney, AEST (Australian Eastern Standard Time) starts on the first Sunday of April and AEDT (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) starts on the first Sunday of October.

So I thought, if I could find a formula that detects whether a date falls between the first Sunday of April and first Sunday of October (Standard Time) then I can automatically add 1 hour to the usual 2 hours to Manila time during Daylight Saving Time (dates falling outside the two dates) to have Sydney Time.

These two Excel solutions worked fine in Google Sheets:

- [How You Can Determine the First Sunday in a Month in Excel](https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/how-you-can-determine-the-first-sunday-in-a-month-in-excel)
- [How to determine if a date falls between two dates or on weekend in Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/956-excel-date-falls-between-two-dates.html#a1)

First Sunday of April this year (A1):

```
=CONCATENATE("4/1/",Year(today()))+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE("4/1/",Year(today())),1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

First Sunday of October this year (A2):

```
=CONCATENATE("10/1/",year(today()))+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE("10/1/",year(today())),1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

DST detector (A3) — if a date falls outside these two dates, it's DST in Sydney:

```
=IF(AND(today()>A1,today()<A2),"AEST","AEDT")
```

Time in Sydney (A4):

```
=NOW()+TIME(IF(A3="AEDT",3,2),0,0)
```

`NOW()` can be changed to any time format for tabulation:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I'm curious about why do you don't want to use a custom funtion. Is this about a concern regarding the impact on the spreadsheet performance? Could you share briefly a use case where you found better to use your solution rather than using a custom function?

Comment: @Rubén It's not really about spreadsheet performance. It's just that I'm not yet comfortable with programming so I felt I'd try other solutions first before trying custom functions. If I needed to convert many time zones, I believe using your custom function would be more efficient. ;)

Comment: @Wicket the 1st link is dead. Can you please explain what the "4/1" and "10/1" were obtained from the 1st 2 formulas? I'm trying to get the last Sunday of March (26 March 2023) and October (29 October 2023) from this year but I'm not sure how to modify accordingly.
"3/19" to "3/25" returns March 26th in this formula:
`=CONCATENATE("3/25/2023")+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE("3/25/2023"),1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1)` and "10/22" to "10/28" returns October 29th in this formula:
=CONCATENATE("10/28/2023")+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(CONCATENATE("10/28/2023"),1),7,6,5,4,3,2,1). How can this be made dynamic for each year?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a new contributor and a novice, but I stumbled upon a function that had not been mentioned despite many hours of searching on the Sheets/Time Zone issue.  Hoping this relatively simple solution will help.

For my sheet, I just want to add a row and automatically populate the local sheet date and time in the first two cells.

The .getTimezoneOffset() returns the difference in minutes between the client TZ and GMT, which in NY during Daylight Savings Time is 240.  The function returns a positive number for the zones with "GMT-x", and vice versa for zones with "GMT+x".  Hence the need to divide by -60 to get the correct hour and sign.

```
function addRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRows(2, 1);
  rightNow = new Date();
  var tzOffset = "GMT" + rightNow.getTimezoneOffset() / -60;
  var fDate = Utilities.formatDate(rightNow, tzOffset, "MM-dd-yyyy");
  var fTime = Utilities.formatDate(rightNow, tzOffset, "HH:mm");
  sheet.getRange('A2').setValue(fDate);
  sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(fTime);
  sheet.getRange('C2').setValue(tzOffset);
}
```

I've since found that I'm not the first person to respond to the GMT correction connundrum mentioning .getTimezoneOffset().  However, this thread has the most views on this topic, so I figured this option deserves a mention.

DST ends here on November 7th, 2021, so I'll report back if it doesn't adjust as expected to "GMT-5"

[.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Answer (score 0):

That can also be done without macros. Just using functions and data manipulation will suffice. Explaning the whole process here would be a bit cumbersome. Just do your research on how the various time functions work and use your creativity.

Hint: Use `=NOW()` if you want both current date and time. You'll actually need that if you need to find out the precise diff in time between to different dates.

Use `=NOW()-INT(NOW())` when you only want the time (with date truncated if both times fall on the same date). Then format the corresponding cell or cells for time (i.e. `4:30 PM`), not for date-time (`3/25/2019 17:00:00`). The latter is the format you'd use when you want to show both date and time... like when you use `NOW()`.

Also search online for the Daylight Saving Time offset for the various standard time zones (PT, MT, CT, ET, AT) with respect to the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). For example, in 2019 the offset for Pacific Time is UTC-7 when DST is observed starting on March 10 at 2 AM (Pacific) until November 3 at 2 AM. That means that the difference in time from UTC to Pacific is 7 hours. During the rest of the year is 8 hours (UTC-8). During DST observance starting sometime in March (the 10th this yr) it goes from PST to PDT by moving clocks forward 1 hr, or what we know as UTC-7 (that's summer time). After DST observance it goes from PDT to PST by moving clocks back 1 hr again, or what we know as UTC-8 (or winter time). Remember that the clock is advanced one hour in March to make better use of time. That's what we call DST, or Daylight Saving Time. So after March 8 at 2 AM (this year in 2019) we are in UTC-7. In November, we do the opposite. In Nov 3 at 2 AM the clock is taken back one hour as the winter kicks in. At that point we are back in Standard Time. Seems a bit confusing but it's really not.

So, basically, for folks in PT they go from PST to PDT in March and from PDT to PST in November. The exact same process goes on with Mountain Time, Central Time and Eastern Time. But they have different UTC time offsets. MT is either UTC-6 or UTC-7. CT is either UTC-5 or UTC-6. And ET is either UTC-4 or UTC-5. All depending on whether we are in summer time when Daylight Saving is observed to make better use of daylight and working hours, or in winter time (AKA, Standard Time).

Study these thoroughly and understand how they work, and play around with the various time functions in Excel or Google Sheets like the `TIME(#,#,#)` and `NOW()` functions and such, and believe me, soon you'll be able to do about anything like a pro with plain functions without having to use <s>VBA</s> Google Apps Script. You can also use the `TEXT()` function, though, with tricks like `=TEXT(L4,"DDD, MMM D")&" | "&TEXT(L4,"h:mm AM/PM")`, where L4 contains you date-timestamp, to display time and date formats. The `VALUE()` function also comes in handy every now and then. You can even design a numerical countdown timer without the use of macros. You'd need to create a circular reference and set iterations to 1, and time display to say every 1 min, in your spreadsheet settings for that.

The official timeanddate dot com website is a good source of info for all to know about time zones and how daylight time is handled. They have all UTC offsets there too.

Comment: "Study these thoroughly"? Not a good idea. Time zones are nearly as tricky as cryptography. Always rely on a very well-tested library.

Comment: I second that - hardcoding is not the way to go.. what happens when the EU abolishes daylight savings? and the EU and US both change clocks in march but not on the same day like they used to - weeks apart.

Comment: This question is about Google Sheets, not Excel so I made a slight correction.

Comment: I third the disapproval of writing your own timezone library.  Timezones are messy and change on a legislative whim.  So unless you want to commit to tracking all of the latest changes to Daylight Savings Times rules from here on out, you should use a library!

Comment: I find it's best to stick to GMT/UTC when storing the data and then convert as necessary

Answer (score -1):

Create your own Timezone Converter in Google Sheets:

**Step 1:** [Create your table for the timezone converter.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZKfo.png)

**Step 2:** [Enter the times for your time zones in a column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnWoE.png)
Note: Ensure that you select date/time format(Select Cell(s) -> Format -> Number -> Time/Date)

**Step 3:** Write a formula to convert timezone using the following functions
[Google Sheet Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf9iD.png)

```
=HOUR(A8)+(B3*C3) converts the hours.
=MINUTE(A8)+(B3*C3) converts the minutes.
```

**Step 4:** Convert back to time format using TIME(h,m,s) function

```
=TIME(HOUR(A8)+(B3*C3), MINUTE(A8)+(B3*C3), SECOND(A8))
```

This is a simple way to convert timezones. 
However, if you want to implement an accurate timezone converter that takes care of the previous day, next day, and beyond 24 hours, beyond 60 minutes, please use MOD operations and handle all the cases. 
Visit(or Use) this google sheet for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tfz5AtU3pddb46PG93HFlzpE8zqy421N0MKxHBCSqpo/edit?usp=sharing