# Google Sheets format time incorrectly

Tags: time, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In my software for calling I have time in format 02:35 (duration of the call). I just highlight it and ctrl+c. Then I go to my google sheets and paste this text via ctrl+v into the corresponding column. The column formatting is hh:mm:ss. But after pasting I've got 02:35:00, instead of 00:02:35

I tried different types of formatting the column, but nothing has worked.
I can't use formulas to make such formatting because a large team of people do the same procedures in their own sheets, so it should be automatically

Comment: This very likely has to do with how the data is inserted in the first place. Can you please tell us a bit more about how those durations are added to your sheet? And maybe share a copy of it (after removing possibly confidential information)?

Comment: In my software for calling I have time in format 02:35 (duration of the call). I just highlight it and ctrl+c.
Then I go to my google sheets and paste this text via ctrl+v into the corresponding column.
The column formatting is hh:mm:ss. 
But after pasting I've got 02:35:00, instead of 00:02:35

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format cell as minutes : seconds in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038093/format-cell-as-minutes-seconds-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: @Tedinoz cool way, but too difficult for a large team that makes such procedures in their own sheets

Comment: @VelGreen Your question suggests a single user (you) and no frequency of copy/paste. Please edit your question to clarify that this is "a large team" creating/editing their own sheets - you might also care to expand on what that actually means.

Answer (score 2):

pre-format the column in which you paste stuff to **Plain text**:

[image: 0]

if that's not enought then use this formula to fix your times:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"", TEXT("00:"&A:A, "mm:ss"), ))
```

[image]