# Filtering fastest and average time in Google Sheets

Tags: time, google-sheets, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I wanna add times for example 12:24 or 25:32 and then filter out the fastest or the average time.

I'm doing a sheet for dungeon runtimes. I wanna enter the times in a format like 25:52 (mm:ss) or similar. Then I wanna filter out the fastest run as well as the average time to run a dungeon.

Here's a list of times that get converted easily with this line.
The problem with this is that I can't filter on the results.

```
19:55
20:10
22:35
25:44
27:22
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"", TEXT("00:"&A:A, "mm:ss"), ))
```

I've encountered problems formating the time. Either i need to add the times as 0:25:32 or it gets converted into 1:32 AM. If I convert the times as shown in this post. I'm getting troubles then filtering out the fastest time. [Google Sheets format time incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724214/google-sheets-format-time-incorrectly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUM:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SUM(IF(A:A<>"", TIME(0, LEFT(A:A, 2), RIGHT(A:A, 2)), )), "[mm]:ss"))
```

### AVG:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(AVERAGE(IF(A:A<>"", TIME(0, LEFT(A:A, 2), RIGHT(A:A, 2)), )), "[mm]:ss"))
```

### MIN:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(MIN(IF(A:A<>"", TIME(0, LEFT(A:A, 2), RIGHT(A:A, 2)), )), "[mm]:ss"))
```

---

[image: 0]

or if you want hours too then use `"[h]:mm:ss"`

also format your A column as **Plain text** if you enter time in format `MM:SS`

Comment: I have the same request but my column is a duration so your function to average doesn't work

Comment: @dubis can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I found there were empty cells

Comment: I ask a new question : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139822/g-sheet-how-to-get-average-duration-time